# Security issues with rights to Network Service account

Tags: asp.net, security

i have a page where the user can upload files on the server. Due to some problem related to account rights it was not working.

Then i gave full rights to the Network Service account. 
I just wanted to know if there are any security breaching related issues with this solution, because i will be publishing the same to the client.

If there are problems with this then kindly help with proper solution.

any help will be appreciated...
thank you.

Comment: Full rights to what (folder, machine, ...)?

Comment: giving full rights to the Network Service account for your folder on the hosted server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are.

If you have other applications running on the *same server* with NETWORK SERVICE, if those applications are compromised, they can access whatever resources you've allowed for YOUR app running under NETWORK SERVICE.

This is not a problem when you have single-purpose machines, which run your application and ONLY your application.

But say you have another app on there written by a junior programmer, which also runs NETWORK SERVICE.  It's not important what it does... If that *other* application gets compromised in some way, an attacker could get to YOUR resource though that *other* application because you're running as the same user (NETWORK SERVICE).

Comment: Thanks buddy that info was really very helpful : )
take care